# How to handle unfinished work, but keep the charts in shape?

Tags: tfs, scrum

We recently finished our first couple of sprints and some questions were raised to which we don't quite know the answer.

Both questions are related to: what should we do with backlog items, tasks and bugs which are not completed when the sprint ends? And how will a certain action influence a burndown or velocity chart?

If we have a 20 day sprint, my guess was that we should start on day 1, stop on day 20, leave one day for the next sprint meeting (day 21) and start the next sprint on day 22.

Let's say we have a PBI which has 3 tasks. One task is Done, one is In Progress and one was put back to To Do. The PBI has an effort of 6. If we move items in or out of the sprint during the sprint this has an influence on the Sprint Burndown and the Velocity chart. But once the sprint ended, and we move these items, does it still affect the charts? Or how should we handle such items? Should we close the PBI (set it to Done, even though it's not) or just move it and leave the tasks that were done in the previous sprint? Should we set all tasks to Done, even though some aren't? Each task has been worked on, so hours were used. We need to keep track of those, or at least, the velocity chart should still be OK.

A similar question rose for a bug. We added a Testing state, so instead of setting the state to Done, the developer sets it to Testing, so the test team knows which PBI's or bugs to test, and sets it to Done once it's completed. If a bug arises from a PBI, we close the PBI and open a bug for it. But if it's a bug, and it's not fixed, they reopen it. Either by setting it to Approved or Committed, but what happens with the efforts that were assigned to it? If the bug is not fixed when the sprint ended, should we set it to Done and open a new one, or just move it to the next sprint?

Comment: This should be posted to http://programmers.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrum has been slightly revised and clarified over time; the latest version is more or less specified in [The Scrum Guide (2011)](http://www.scrum.org/Scrum-Guides)

- The Sprint Planning Meeting is part of the Sprint and it typically performed on the first day of the sprint (Day 1).  Day 20 Will contain Sprint Review and Retrospective. Day 21 is actually Day 1 of the subsequent Sprint.
- Regarding your question about the unfinished Product Backlog Item (PBI): Your goal is to establish a velocity for your team over time. **CONSISTENCY** is key to this. So most importantly, you should *establish a way of doing it the same every Sprint*. I see teams handle this is different ways;  You need to determine if you actually delivered the Sprint Backlog Item based on what got done.  If the value wasn't delivered, then you can leave it as not done and optionally update the final work on the tasks.  You can also put a note in the history and/or description of the Sprint Backlog item about what was accompished and the acceptance criteria achieved. If the value of the item was delivered to some degree then you might make a similar note and count the item. You need not be exact about the points covered in the Sprint since they will average out over time, so you just need to use your judgement.  Whatever is not done can be made a Product Backlog Item and prioritized accordingly. Your Product Owner may decide to put it lower on the Product backlog depending on the value of what was not finished in it.  When the PBI representing the unfinished work, you will create a new set of tasks for it (you might copy the ones that were not completed from the Sprint in which they were not completed to save time).  What is also important here is to discuss how things went and how you can handle this moving forward during your Sprint Review and Sprint Retrospective so your team can adjust accordingly.
- Regarding the Bug, you might consider handling it similarly to the PBI for planning and prioritizing and Done / not done; your team needs a definition of done; if this includes testing, you should consider it Done only after testing.  If it is not done then again you should handle that in a consistent way.  Out of the box, the Scrum 1.0 version of the Bug work item has a state named Committed that indicates that the Bug is ready for testing, so you shouldn't need that testing state. Once it passes testing, it goes from Committed to the Done state. You can find the [Process Guidance for the Scrum 1.0 template on the Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731587).  It is more or less the instructions for how to work with the template.